# In a logistic regression, is it possible to have predicted probabilities that run counter to the beta values?

Tags: logistic

I've run a logistic regression on some data with 3 categorical independent variables, and a binary dependent variable. I've plotted the predicted probabilities as a way of visualising the significant interactions, but have found that despite the beta value being negative for some variables, the predicted probabilities show increases for those levels.

For example, there is an effect of condition with the output suggesting that the dependent variable is 3.81 times more likely to be 1 for condition 1. However, when plotted, condition 1 has much lower predicted probabilities.

Is this possible, or does it indicate something has been done incorrectly?

---

UPDATE:
Apologies for the quality of the graph and annotation, but here is what I mean - I have plotted the likelihoods for each condition, at each time point and across students and non-students:

[image: Graphs]

The issue I have is that I cannot explain why some of these look so different to the statistics I'm reporting; there is apparently no difference in the likelihood of having a value of 1 in the DV (0 is my reference category) between time 1 and time 2 in condition 1 for students, although this looks like the biggest difference in the plot. Similarly, there is apparently an increased likelihood of having a value of 1 between time 2 and time 3 for non-students, although the plot suggests a decrease.

Is there a reason why this might be the case?

Comment: Could you add the intercept and coefficients of the model to your question, or even better: the code required for others to replicate the problem? A positive coefficient for a category compared to its reference, or in a multivariable model a higher linear predictor as a whole should result in a higher predicted probability. So the predicted probability should not run counter the betas. Not to be rude, but to me it seems either something went wrong in your coding, or your interpretation.

Comment: Please show us what you're seeing.

Comment: I've added a picture of the graph in case that helps.

Comment: Also, yes, I'm entirely willing to accept the error here is in the coding or interpretation, so it's not rude at all! I don't have the code to replicate the problem, as I'm running the analyses in SPSS but hopefully the graph will provide some additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this can happen is that there is mediation between the variables.  That is, the effect of the variable is different when the other variables are added to the model.  Since all three independent variables are categorical, you can make a table of all the combinations of levels of the IVs.

Another possibility is that you are choosing the reference categories of the IVs incorrectly, or interpreting the output incorrectly.

A third possibility is that you are coding the dependent variable incorrectly without knowing it.  In SAS, for instance, the default choice when the DV is coded as 0 and 1 is to model the probability of a 0.  One way to fix this is with the `descending` option.